# Open Page As New Tab In Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

We are not able to open a page as new tab in Google chrome. We are able to successfully open page as new tab in Internet Explorer, Mozilla and Safari.

Just for your information we have added "_blank" in "window.open" which have successfully opened page as new tab in all 3 browsers (Internet Explorer, Mozilla and Safari) except in Google Chrome.

Can any one please let us know what changes we should do to open a page as new tab in Google Chrome?

Regards
Tarunjit Singh

Answer (score 0):

If you did it with javascript, this script may be useful:

```
function RedirectToPage(status) {
   var url = 'ObjectEditor.aspx?Status=' + status;
   window.open(url , '_blank');
}
```